# Add current authenticated username to image and/or video filename

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, filenames

I'm trying to figure out how I would get the data in a Firebase database assigned to a particular user but that is proving very tricky for me.

So, for now, I would like to be able to attach the current signed-in/authenticated user's name/ID to any file that I save from my app but I don't know how to go about it.

I tried adding the following lines to my Camera Photo activity but it didn't do anything:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
```

and then adding to the code where it assigns the file name (as such):

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() + ".jpg");
```

But, as I say, it doesn't do anything and just keeps the file name in the same format without any user ID associated with it.

Below is the full class for taking and saving a photo (without my added attempts):

```
public class CameraPhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnCapture;
private TextureView textureView;

// to check the state orientation of the output image
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}

private String cameraId;
private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
private Size imageDimension;
private ImageReader imageReader;

// save to file
private File file;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
private boolean mFlashSupported;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice = camera;
        createCameraPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_photo);

    textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    assert textureView != null;
    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    btnCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            takePicture();
        }
    });
}

private void takePicture() {

    if (cameraDevice == null)
        return;
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
        Size[] jpegSizes = null;
        if (characteristics != null)
            jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                    .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

        // capture the image with custom size
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0) {
            width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
            height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
        }
        final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
        List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
        outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
        outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

        // check the orientation on the device
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                +  ".jpg");
        ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                Image image = null;
                try {
                    image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                    buffer.get(bytes);
                    save(bytes);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    {
                        if (image != null)
                            image.close();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                OutputStream outputStream = null;
                try {
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    outputStream.write(bytes);
                } finally {
                    if (outputStream != null)
                        outputStream.close();
                }

                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(CameraPhotoActivity.this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("External Storage", "Scanned" + path + ":");
                                Log.i("External Storage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                            }
                        });

            }
        };

        reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
        final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                Toast.makeText(CameraPhotoActivity.this, "Saved " + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                createCameraPreview();
            }
        };

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                try {
                    cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);


    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void createCameraPreview() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                if (cameraDevice == null)
                    return;
                cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Toast.makeText(CameraPhotoActivity.this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updatePreview() {
    if (cameraDevice == null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    try {
        cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void openCamera() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        assert map != null;
        imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
        // check realtime permission if run higher than API 23
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            }, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
        manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
        openCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

    }
};

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You can't use the camera without permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startBackgroundThread();
    if (textureView.isAvailable())
        openCamera();
    else
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    stopBackgroundThread();
    super.onPause();
}

private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        mBackgroundThread.join();
        mBackgroundThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
}
}
```

Also, here is my login authentication class:

```
public class MainLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mEmailField;
private EditText mPasswordField;

private Button mLoginBtn;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

private boolean isUserClickedBackButton = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

    mLoginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

    // connection to user authentication on firebase (database)
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){

                startActivity(new Intent(MainLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }

        }
    };

    mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startSiginIn();


        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
// code for exiting from app by using back button on login page
public void onBackPressed() {
    //moveTaskToBack(true);
    if (!isUserClickedBackButton){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isUserClickedBackButton = true;
    } else {
        System.exit(0); // exits right out of app
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
}


// for login
private void startSiginIn() {

    String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "Please input email and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (!task.isSuccessful())

                    Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "Sign in problem.  Please check email" +
                            " and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Again, any help and advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You say it keep your image name in the same format. Which is this format?

Comment: @AlexMamo it stores it in the internal storage and gives it a unique ID and stores it as a jpg file

Comment: What is the format of that unique id?

Comment: @AlexMamo An example is: 1518736735803.jpg

Comment: So isn't this id what the `UUID.randomUUID` is generating?

Comment: It is but I want the actual username to be saved in the file. Is there no way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the user name in the name of your file, you need to change this line of code:

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() + ".jpg");
```

with

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() + ".jpg");
```

See, I have added a call to `.getDisplayName()` method.

Comment: Do I need the onStart method in the  photo activity class?

Comment: It depends on your use-case of the app. But you can use this also in your `onCreate()` method. So have you tried? Does it work?

Comment: No it doesn't work but I don't think it's because what you are saying is wrong.  I'm probably just not putting everything I need into the class and/or in the right places